# Why does Django create a new instance instead of update?

Tags: django

I want to modify some of my 'Location' object with an UpdateView.

```
class LocationUpdateView(UpdateView):
    #form_class = LocationForm
    model = LocationTemplate
    fields = ['address','district','grid_x','grid_y']
    #template_name = 'locationTemplate_update_form'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('location_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            self.object = self.get_object()
            for loc in Location.objects.all():
                if self.object.location_name == loc.location_name:

                    setattr(loc,'address',(form.cleaned_data['address']))
                    setattr(loc,'district',(form.cleaned_data['district']))
                    setattr(loc,'grid_x',(form.cleaned_data['grid_x']))
                    setattr(loc,'grid_y',(form.cleaned_data['grid_y']))

                    loc.save()

            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

However, instead of updating the objects, the above loop creates a new object with the update information(except the location_name is None). I was expecting setattr() to modify the attributes of that specific loc instead of creating new instances.

models.py

```
class LocationTemplate(models.Model):
    location_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    district = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    grid_x = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    grid_y = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.location_name + ", Address: " + self.address + ", District: " + self.district + ", Coordinates: (" + str(self.grid_x) + ", " + str(self.grid_y) + ")"
```

forms.py

```
class LocationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = LocationTemplate
        #exclude = ('patient',)
        fields=['location_name', 'address','district', 'grid_x','grid_y']
```

Comment: you are not using correctly ViewUpdate. it is not necessary to mapper the attributes. just use form.save() it will do the work for you. as you ask for what fields to be changed in the form it does it by itself. please check this out and follow the documentation. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, problem is with the call to `self.get_form`

This call returns a form initialized with the model instance in case of update, and it passes the return value of `self.get_object()` to the form when creating. In your code, `self.object` is not set until after `get_form`.

TLDR:
move
`self.object = self.get_object()`
above
`form = self.get_form()`

You should not need any of the `setattr` logic or the loop, the `UpdateView` handles identifying the instance to be updated, and the `Form` handles the attribute mapping/updating on the model.